# package declaration auto suggest keyboard shortcut

Tags: intellij-idea

I am new to using IntelliJ Idea for my Java development. I created a java class and declared the package statement. However, I want the package structure to be created and the class file to be present inside the package that I declare. I noticed that the auto suggest feature is not working when I hover on the package statement even when I tried to hit the control + spacebar. I am on Mac and not sure what I am missing. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: I gave this a go and it seems to work alright in my environment.  I make use of Alt + Return instead of Ctrl + Spacebar though.  It's tough to say what's going wrong, but I suspect that you should use Alt + Return when you're on the package name so that you can get the option to move the class to the right package for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your package while creating your file. Right click on your source-folder (e.g. `src`) and select `New > Java Class` (or press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>). Now type your package structure followed by the class name, e.g. `com.example.MyClass`. The class will be created with the proper package structure.

If your package structure already exists, you can select this package and create a new class without writing the package path. It will be placed automatically within this package.